# Система охлаждения в корпусе ПК

Tags: железо

Есть ли смысл ставить дополнительные вентиляторы в корпус с боковой сеткой?

На видеокарте и процессоре также стоят кулеры. Компьютер больше офисный чем игровой.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик.

Comment: На этом сайте обсуждаются только вопросы программирования и системного администрирования. Про железо и его обслуживание — оффтопик.

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте

В любом случае корпусные кулеры не повредят, т.к. могут греться не только процессор и видеокарта, но и элементы материнской платы.

Однако, если ПК офисный и температуры основных компонентов в норме, то можно пренебречь установкой корпусных кулеров.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но не особо принесет результата. Особенно в офисном компе. Если греется - имеет смысл вычистить пыль и сменить термопасту, проверить, чтобы не был закрыт доступ для забора воздуха уже имеющимися кулерами